# How to deal with the boolean operator when their length don't match in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Given such a data frame `a` and `idx`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
idx = np.array([False, False, True, True, False])
a = pd.Dataframe(np.full((5),0))
```

I want to add `n` to `a` and the `n` denotes the number of `True` before the position of each value. Hence, `a` should become: `0,0,1,2,2`. Do you know how to do it in a vectorised way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you want `cumsum`:

```
In [106]:
pd.DataFrame(idx).cumsum()

Out[106]:
   0
0  0
1  0
2  1
3  2
4  2
```

your question is a little unclear but you can use the boolean array itself and call `cumsum` which will convert the `True` to `1`